# IFrame horizontal scrollbar annoyance

Tags: jquery, html

No matter what I make the size of the IFrame, the website within won't fit it.

I've tried a number of things but none of them seem to work.

There is also a vertical scrollbar but I'm fine with that being there. But horizontally, I'd like the website to "wrap" the IFrame window perfectly such that there is no need for the horizontal scrollbar. How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;` maybe

Comment: Do you have some code to show your problem?

Comment: if the site you're using the iframe for has a fixed width, there isn't much you can do. The only thing would probably hide the scrollbar, which 19greg96 showed how.

Comment: Stupid question, but if you display the inner HTML page normally in a browser window, does it have a scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the website on the same domain (it was not on the same server but the server is owned by our company) and that seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

iFrames are a bit.. odd (and a bit bad practice, but ok)...

```
<iframe id="treeFrame" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

you need to set the src though...